# Unable to unit test a service that uses $http without calling scope.$digest

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service in my application that makes use of `$http`, formatting requests according to a particular spec. I have been trying to run unit tests on the service's methods, using `$httpBackend` to mock up responses. I have not had any trouble with this when testing my controllers and directives that use `$http`, but with my service I have been having difficulty.

I've been following the pattern in the first answer here:
[AngularJS - Testing service method that uses $http service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084410/angularjs-testing-service-method-that-uses-http-service)

i.e., register an expected request with `$httpBackend`, define a response to it, call the service's method of interest, and then flush the backend mock.

I'm unable to get this to work unless I inject `$rootScope`, create a new scope and run a `$digest()` on it after calling my service method of interest. This is the pattern I use with testing controllers and directives that use `$http`, as the test runner will indicate there are no pending requests to flush otherwise. However, I was not expecting this requirement in a service, as `scope` does not make a great deal of sense in one to me. Additionally, the answer in the question linked above does not indicate that this is explicitly necessary.

After poking around in the angular source for a fairly large deal of time this morning, I determined that a promise object is made successfully for my service's `$http` request, but that the promise resolution functions registered in `$q.when`'s call to `nextTick()` never fire. Only when I add a line to digest a scope object in my servicesSpec will everything fire....

Is this a known issue? I am using v1.2.0rc2. Are there workarounds to uncouple testing services from scope objects?

For reference, here is the spec code that functions:

```
describe("widget services", function () {

  beforeEach(module('widget.services'));

  describe("WidgetDB", function () {
    var service, $httpBackend, scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, WidgetDB, _$httpBackend_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      service = WidgetDB;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    it("should do something", function () {
      $httpBackend.expectPOST(myUrl).respond(myResponse);
      service.getChartData(myArguments);
      scope.$digest(); // why do I need this for testing services?                                                                                                              
      $httpBackend.flush();
      /* test evaluations */
    });

    afterEach(function () {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });


  });

});
```

Comment: What does you service function (getChartData) look like?

Comment: `getChartData` formats some data and calls `$http.post()`. Even in a highly reduced form of simply `$http.post(myUrl);`, the serviceSpec requires me to run a `scope.$digest()` in order to have a pending request to flush.

Comment: Are you doing anything "outside" of Angular, like with a jQuery plugin or something in the service method? Really, including the source for that function would be helpful in coming up with the solution.